# Troubleshooting Spring TestContext caching

Tags: spring-test

Spring TestContext Framework caches context based on several keys.

How can I log cache keys to ensure that my tests reuse contexts?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As documented in the [Context Caching](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.1.2.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/testing.html#testcontext-ctx-management-caching) section of the Spring Reference Manual...

> Since having a large number of application contexts loaded within a given test suite can cause the suite to take an unnecessarily long time to execute, it is often beneficial to know exactly how many contexts have been loaded and cached. To view the statistics for the underlying context cache, you can set the log level for the `org.springframework.test.context.cache` logging category to `DEBUG`.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to supporting Sam's answer here is what you can see if enable `DEBUG` level on `org.springframework.test.context.cache`:

```
DEBUG org.springframework.test.context.BootstrapUtils
  Instantiating CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate from class [org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate]

DEBUG org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate
  Storing ApplicationContext in cache under key
  [[MergedContextConfiguration testClass = XTest,
    locations = '{}',
    classes = '{...}',
    contextInitializerClasses = '[...]',
    activeProfiles = '{}',
    propertySourceLocations = '{classpath:application-test.properties}',
    propertySourceProperties = '{...}', contextCustomizers = set[...],
    contextLoader = 'org.springframework.test.context.support.AnnotationConfigContextLoader',
    parent = [null]]]

DEBUG org.springframework.test.context.cache
  Spring test ApplicationContext cache statistics:
  [DefaultContextCache@6ef2f7ad size = 1, maxSize = 32, parentContextCount = 0, hitCount = 0, missCount = 1]

DEBUG org.springframework.test.context.cache
  Spring test ApplicationContext cache statistics:
  [DefaultContextCache@6ef2f7ad size = 1, maxSize = 32, parentContextCount = 0, hitCount = 6, missCount = 1]
```

It is hard to read cache key details but following cache statistics information says for itself.